# Personality Rights: Text vs Images in Commercial Works

Tags: united-states

I can't use a person's "image" in advertising without permission, but I believe one can legally write about famous people without their permission. I think the legal term is "expressive." But what about pictures - either photos or illustrations? Can they be regarded as expressive as well, or are they in a category of their own?

For example, imagine someone writing a book titled *The Naughty Side of Hollywood*, which discusses celebrities who had criminal records, were notorious adulterers, etc. Would it be legal to include a photo - either in the public domain or from Creative Commons - of each celebrity profiled without permission?

Wikipedia does it, of course, but it's technically non-profit.

**Edit:** My question focuses on the content inside the book, not the cover.

Comment: Thanks, but that focuses on book covers. I'm talking about using pictures to accompany the text inside the book.

Comment: @Paredon The placement of the picture has little to do with its legality, in terms of right of publicity.

Comment: I've read that placing a picture in an ad is illegal, while putting it on a book's cover may also be considered advertising. Are you saying that putting a picture inside a book is also a form of advertising?